# WPF Bitmap / BitmapFrame to multi-page / multi-frame TIFF with JPEG encoding

Tags: c#, image, wpf, compression

I was searching for a long time how to write multi-page TIFFs with the JPEG encoding. TIFFs support JPEG encoded frames but the built-in encoder in .NET Framework does not have JPEG as a compression option.

The code is based on the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811496/tiff-with-jpeg-compression-much-larger-than-original-jpeg
but does not rely on the FreeImage library.

First up, a class to convert `BitmapFrame` or `Bitmap` to a JPEG image:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace TIFF
{
    public class Jpeg
    {
        public byte[] Data;
        public uint Width;
        public uint Height;
        public uint HorizontalResolution;
        public uint VerticalResolution;

        public Jpeg(byte[] data, uint width, uint height, uint horizontalResolution, uint verticalResolution)
        {
            this.Data = data;
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;
            this.HorizontalResolution = horizontalResolution;
            this.VerticalResolution = verticalResolution;
        }

        public static Jpeg FromBitmapFrame(BitmapFrame bitmap, long quality)
        {
            Jpeg jpeg;

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.QualityLevel = 90;
                encoder.Frames.Add(bitmap);
                encoder.Save(stream);

                jpeg = new Jpeg(stream.ToArray(), (uint)bitmap.Width, (uint)bitmap.Height, (uint)bitmap.DpiX, (uint)bitmap.DpiY);
            }

            return jpeg;
        }

        public static Jpeg FromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, long quality)
        {
            Jpeg jpeg;
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Encoder encoder = Encoder.Quality;
                EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, quality);
                bitmap.Save(stream, jpgEncoder, parameters);

                jpeg = new Jpeg(stream.ToArray(), (uint) bitmap.Width, (uint) bitmap.Height, (uint) bitmap.HorizontalResolution, (uint) bitmap.VerticalResolution);
            }

            return jpeg;
        }

        private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
        {
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
            {
                if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
                {
                    return codec;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Next, a class to create the TIFF image

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace TIFF
{
    public static class JpegTiff
    {
        public static byte[] Create(List<BitmapFrame> frames, long quality)
        {
            List<Jpeg> jpegs = new List<Jpeg>();

            foreach (var frame in frames)
            {
                jpegs.Add(Jpeg.FromBitmapFrame(frame, quality));
            }

            return WrapJpegs(jpegs);
        }    

        public static byte[] Create(List<Bitmap> bitmaps, string filename, long quality)
        {
            List<Jpeg> jpegs = new List<Jpeg>();

            foreach (var bitmap in bitmaps)
            {
                jpegs.Add(Jpeg.FromBitmap(bitmap, quality));
            }

            return WrapJpegs(jpegs);
        }

        private static byte[] WrapJpegs(List<Jpeg> jpegs)
        {
            if (jpegs == null || jpegs.Count == 0 || jpegs.FindIndex(b => b.Data.Length == 0) > -1)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Image Data must not be null or empty");

            MemoryStream tiffData = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(tiffData);
            uint offset = 8; // size of header, offset to IFD
            ushort entryCount = 14; // entries per IFD

            #region IFH - Image file header

            // magic number
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                writer.Write(0x002A4949);
            else
                writer.Write(0x4D4D002A);

            // offset to (first) IFD
            writer.Write(offset);

            #endregion IFH

            #region IFD Image file directory

            // write image file directories for each jpeg
            for (int i = 0; offset > 0; i++)
            {
                var jpeg = jpegs[i];
                uint width = jpeg.Width;
                uint length = jpeg.Height;
                uint xres = jpeg.HorizontalResolution;
                uint yres = jpeg.VerticalResolution;

                // count of entries:
                writer.Write(entryCount);

                offset += 6 + 12 * (uint)entryCount; // add lengths of entries, entry-count and next-ifd-offset

                // TIFF-fields / IFD-entrys:
                // {TAG, TYPE (3 = short, 4 = long, 5 = rational), COUNT, VALUE/OFFSET}
                uint[,] fields = new uint[,] {
                    {254, 4, 1, 0}, // NewSubfileType
                    {256, 4, 1, width}, // ImageWidth
                    {257, 4, 1, length}, // ImageLength
                    {258, 3, 3, offset}, // BitsPerSample
                    {259, 3, 1, 7}, // Compression (new JPEG)
                    {262, 3, 1, 6}, //PhotometricInterpretation (YCbCr)
                    {273, 4, 1, offset + 22}, // StripOffsets (offset IFH + entries + values of BitsPerSample & YResolution & XResolution)
                    {277, 3, 1, 3}, // SamplesPerPixel
                    {278, 4, 1, length}, // RowsPerStrip
                    {279, 4, 1, (uint)jpegs[i].Data.LongLength}, // StripByteCounts
                    {282, 5, 1, offset + 6}, // XResolution (offset IFH + entries + values of BitsPerSample)
                    {283, 5, 1, offset + 14}, // YResolution (offset IFH + entries + values of BitsPerSample & YResolution)
                    {284, 3, 1, 1}, // PlanarConfiguration (chunky)
                    {296, 3, 1, 2} // ResolutionUnit
                };

                // write fields
                for (int f = 0; f < fields.GetLength(0); f++)
                {
                    writer.Write((ushort)fields[f, 0]);
                    writer.Write((ushort)fields[f, 1]);
                    writer.Write(fields[f, 2]);
                    writer.Write(fields[f, 3]);
                }

                // offset of next IFD
                if (i == jpegs.Count - 1)
                    offset = 0;
                else
                    offset += 22 + (uint)jpegs[i].Data.LongLength; // add values (of fields) length and jpeg length
                writer.Write(offset);

                #region values of fields

                // BitsPerSample
                writer.Write((ushort)8);
                writer.Write((ushort)8);
                writer.Write((ushort)8);

                // XResolution
                writer.Write(xres);
                writer.Write(1);

                // YResolution
                writer.Write(yres);
                writer.Write(1);

                #endregion values of fields

                // actual image Data
                writer.Write(jpegs[i].Data);
            }
            #endregion IFD

            writer.Close();
            return tiffData.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

It could probably be improved by passing in the stream to write to instead of returning a byte array.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> public static Jpeg FromBitmapFrame(BitmapFrame bitmap, long quality)
> {
>   Jpeg jpeg;
>   using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
>   {
>     JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
>     encoder.QualityLevel = 90;
>     encoder.Frames.Add(bitmap);
>     encoder.Save(stream);
>     jpeg = new Jpeg(stream.ToArray(), (uint)bitmap.Width, (uint)bitmap.Height, (uint)bitmap.DpiX, (uint)bitmap.DpiY);
>   }
>   return jpeg;
> }
> ```

Here it should be safe to return from inside the `using` statement:

```
public static Jpeg FromBitmapFrame(BitmapFrame bitmap, long quality)
{
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.QualityLevel = 90;
    encoder.Frames.Add(bitmap);
    encoder.Save(stream);
    return new Jpeg(stream.ToArray(), (uint)bitmap.Width, (uint)bitmap.Height, (uint)bitmap.DpiX, (uint)bitmap.DpiY);
  }
}
```

---

> ```
>     private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
>     {
>         ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
>         foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
>         {
>             if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
>             {
>                 return codec;
>             }
>         }
>         return null;
>     }
> ```

Using LINQ this can be reduced to a oneliner:

```
private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{
  return ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == format.Guid);
}
```

---

> ```
> public static byte[] Create(List<BitmapFrame> frames, long quality)
> {
>   List<Jpeg> jpegs = new List<Jpeg>();
>   foreach (var frame in frames)
>   {
>     jpegs.Add(Jpeg.FromBitmapFrame(frame, quality));
>   }
>   return WrapJpegs(jpegs);
> }
> ```

Again LINQ can "modernize" this a little:

```
public static byte[] Create(IEnumerable<BitmapFrame> frames, long quality)
{
  return WrapJpegs(frames.Select(frame => Jpeg.FromBitmapFrame(frame, quality)).ToList());
}
```

---

> `jpegs.FindIndex(b => b.Data.Length == 0) > -1`

LINQ:

```
jpegs.Any(j => j.Data.Length == 0)
```

IMO easier to read.

---

> ```
>         MemoryStream tiffData = new MemoryStream();
>         BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(tiffData);
> ```

You need to wrap these in `using` statements:

```
  using (MemoryStream tiffData = new MemoryStream()) // HDH Use using in order to clean up 
  using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(tiffData))
  {
     ...
    writer.Flush();
    return tiffData.ToArray();
  }
```

---

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; offset > 0; i++)
>       {
> ```

The stop condition is confusing. Why not just use `jpegs.Count` because you actually iterate through all items anyway.

---

In the main loop you declare this:

```
var jpeg = jpegs[i];
```

But you use `jpegs[i]` several times in the loop. Be consistent.

---

> ```
>       uint[,] fields = new uint[,] {
>                 {254, 4, 1, 0}, // NewSubfileType
>                 {256, 4, 1, width}, // ImageWidth
> ```

I think I would make a struct or class for these fields in order to be strict with types - hence avoiding the casting.

---

> ```
>       writer.Write((ushort)8);
>       writer.Write((ushort)8);
>       writer.Write((ushort)8);
> ```

make a `const ushort bitsPerSample = 8;` for this - before the loop.

---

The idea of having a `stream` as argument to the methods is good, but be aware that `BinaryWriter` disposes the stream, when it is disposed unless you use the constructor with the `leaveOpen` flag.

Comment: Nice stuff with the LINQ, looks great. BTW is it better to edit the original question with these changes or post another answer?

Comment: @geometrikal: You're not allowed to change the question once an answer has been posted. Feel free to make an answer with the changes or post a new question with an updated version :-)

Answer (score 4):

Henrik covered a number of points which I would have raised, so I won't repeat those.

---

> ```
> namespace TIFF
> {
>     public class Jpeg
> ```

seems inconsistent to me. The convention in .Net is to camel-case acronyms and initialisms, so the class name is as expected and the namespace is not.

---

> ```
>     public static class JpegTiff
>     {
>         public static byte[] Create(List<BitmapFrame> frames, long quality)
>         ...
>         public static byte[] Create(List<Bitmap> bitmaps, string filename, long quality)
>         ...
>         private static byte[] WrapJpegs(List<Jpeg> jpegs)
>         ...
> ```

Since `Jpeg` is a public class it seems to me that you could rename `WrapJpegs` to `Create` and make it public. That opens up the option, for example, of encoding different frames at different qualities. (I'd also change `List` to `IEnumerable`, as Henrik proposes for the existing `Create` methods).

---

There are some worrying magic numbers. Some of these concerns might be alleviated by a comment with a URL for the file format specification.

> ```
>             uint offset = 8; // size of header, offset to IFD
> ```

Is this 4 for the endianness magic number and 4 for `offset` itself?

> ```
>             ushort entryCount = 14; // entries per IFD
> ```

This is `fields.GetLength(0)`, isn't it? Is there any reason that you can't explicitly use `fields.GetLength(0)` for robustness if you later add or remove a field?

> ```
>                 // TIFF-fields / IFD-entrys:
>                 // {TAG, TYPE (3 = short, 4 = long, 5 = rational), COUNT, VALUE/OFFSET}
>                 uint[,] fields = ...
>
>                 // write fields
>                 for (int f = 0; f < fields.GetLength(0); f++)
>                 {
>                     writer.Write((ushort)fields[f, 0]);
>                     writer.Write((ushort)fields[f, 1]);
>                     writer.Write(fields[f, 2]);
>                     writer.Write(fields[f, 3]);
>                 }
> ```

I find it very confusing that a `short` and a `long` should take the same amount of space.

> ```
>                 if (i == jpegs.Count - 1)
>                     offset = 0;
>                 else
>                     offset += 22 + (uint)jpegs[i].Data.LongLength; // add values (of fields) length and jpeg length
> ```

22? Three shorts and four ints?

One more explicit (although less portable, I admit) approach to these lengths would be to use structs for the chunks of fields and `Marshal.SizeOf`. But I understand if you think that's overkill.

Comment: Some good points. Most of the WrapJpegs code comes from the linked SO question, so I'm still trying to work it out. I would be interested in what using a struct for the chunks of fields looks like